# How can I access URL parameters with Nunjucks?

Tags: nunjucks

I've used twig, which has access to Symphony's `app.request` which can be used to filter url parameters. However, when trying do to something similar with nunjucks, it doesn't seem possible.

I've tried defining `window` on the node process in gulp and passing it to my templates, but that will not work because window won't be defined there.

I'd like to do something as simple as:

```
{% if urlparam|filter('some_param') %}
   {% include 'filter-template' %}
{% else %}
   {% include 'template' %}
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You should provide `urlparam` in render function.

Comment: @AikonMogwai can you explain that? I am running my app using node js and gulp and when I call a render function on the node level, any url params on the url are not viewable because node has no context of `window` since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: When you call the render function you already know url, aren't? So, pass it to render. Otherwise, how can you compile template without this and make it suitable for different urls?

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected html output and file name or url if it worked as you expected

Comment: @Lasithds, i'm sorry i don't understand. if the url string contains a specified url parameter, then i want it to render some arbitrary template, otherwise i want it to render a different arbitrary template. the output doesn't matter as much as the fact that nunjucks can process url parameters.

Comment: Its much easier to do what you want to do  when you are using express with nunjucks, as express has tons of built in option for manipulating URLs